# No access to device storage files

Tags: android

I am trying to store images to a specific folder in the device.

This is the code to store an image:

```
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/capenergy_camera";


private void saveImage() {
        if (requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showLoading("Saving...");
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+IMAGE_DIRECTORY
                    + File.separator + ""
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();

                SaveSettings saveSettings = new SaveSettings.Builder()
                        .setClearViewsEnabled(true)
                        .setTransparencyEnabled(true)
                        .build();

                mPhotoEditor.saveAsFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), saveSettings, new PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull String imagePath) {
                        hideLoading();
                        showSnackbar("Image Saved Successfully");
                        mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        hideLoading();
                        showSnackbar("Failed to save Image");
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                hideLoading();
                showSnackbar(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

I don´t know why the storage folder is always adding the path /emulated/0, and I don´t know how to access that folder.

Example: `/storage/emulated/0/capenergy_camera/1565010745877.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don´t know why the storage folder is always adding the path /emulated/0

In the device filesystem on your device, `/storage/emulated/0` is the root of what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). This is a fairly typical setup.

> I don´t know how to access that folder

Use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio.

Or, use `adb shell`.

Or, plug the device into your development machine via a USB cable and mount what users refer to as "internal storage" (though it is really what the SDK refers to as external storage). Your file will not show up here right away, though, as it is not indexed by the `MediaStore`. Use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` to get it indexed more quickly.

Or, use some on-device file manager, if you have one installed.

Comment: Thank you, but thinking as the app user, how can I access the created images? They don´t appear in the Gallery. At least they don´t appear just after created and saved, they appear a certain time later, and not all of them

Comment: @mvasco: "They don´t appear in the Gallery" -- they are not yet indexed by the `MediaStore`. Use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` to get it indexed more quickly. Also note that [your code will not work on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps), as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is no longer accessible](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).